# problema con select bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap

amigos tengo este código fuente que me permite seleccionar ciudades de un listado con `bootstrap` y mysql.

Todo funcionaba, pero ahora he cambiado la tabla original por una que solo contiene un campo, originalmente tenía un listado de países y la tabla se llamaba `listado_paises`.

Ahora se llama Ciudades y solo contiene un campo llamado nciudades, pero en cuanto cambie esos valores, el `select` desapareció, es necesario tener un campo id, o algún otro campo?

```
input type="text" name="ciudades" id="ciudades" class="form-control" placeholder="ciudad"/>
                    <select class="selectpicker" data-show-subtext="true" data-live-search="true" data-live-search-style="startsWith">
                      <?php
                      include "./c/db.php";
                      $con = connect();
                      if (!$con->set_charset("utf8")) {//asignamos la codificación comprobando que no falle
                            die("Error cargando el conjunto de caracteres utf8");
                      }
                      $consulta = "SELECT * FROM ciudades";
                      $resultado = mysqli_query($con , $consulta);
                      $contador=0;
                      while($misdatos = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){ $contador++;?>
                      <option data-subtext="<?php echo $misdatos["iso"]; ?>"><?php echo $misdatos["nCiudad"]; ?></option>
                      <?php } ?>
                    </select>
```

he probado eliminando el comando `data-subtext` remplazándolo por el mismo campo y quitándolo por completo, pero nada funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si solo tienes un solo campo entonces deberia ser de esta forma:

```
<option data-subtext="<?php echo $misdatos["nCiudad"]; ?></option>
```

o puedes hacerlo por indice utilizando :`mysqli_fetch_array`

```
while($misdatos = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){ $contador++;?>
                      <option data-subtext="<?php echo $misdatos[0]; ?>"> </option>
```

Comment: perfecto muchas gracias Santiago

Comment: si te sirvio califica la respuesta como solucionada.